# Delete old indices elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using the ELK stack for analyzing logs. So as per default configuration a new index by `"logsatash-YYYY-MM-DD"` is created by ES.
So if I have configured logstash to read like this:

```
/var/log/rsyslog/**/2014-12-0[1-7]/auditd.log
```

So it is reading old logs and the index name created will be `"logstash-2015-03-20"`, so this index will have documents (logs) of previous dates.

My problem occurs when I have to delete indexes. If I have to keep only last one weeks data and purge the older indices. When I will delete index names except the last 7 days, I have no track which days logs are kept in which index name. Eg: 2014-12-07 date's logs may be kept in any of index named `logstash-2015-03-19` or `logstash-2015-03-20`.

So how shall I delete indexes??

Comment: You can delete log files which have last "update" > 7 days.

Comment: Nit: The default index pattern for Logstash indexes is logstash-YYYY.MM.DD, not logsatash-YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log messages are stored into indexes based on the value of the @timestamp field (which uses UTC time). If your 2014-12-07 logs end up in 2015-03-19 this timestamp parsing isn't done correctly.

Correct the problem by adding a [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) and/or [date](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) filter and your 2014-12-07 logs will end up in the logstash-2014.12.07 index and it'll be trivial to clean up old logs.

Comment: I am not using the date filter at present. It's like index name is created by the date the ELK setup is made up not by logdate. Eg: I start ELK setup today to read logs of 2014, the index name will be `logstash-TODAY'S DATE`.  So date filter will solve this?

Comment: Yes. The whole purpose of that filter is to set the `@timestamp` field, and that field controls in which index a log message ends up.

Comment: I created a new question for the edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384754/syslog-timestamp-without-year